# Can I view books scanned to PDF on Kindle Classic?

Tags: kindle, pdf

I have many books scanned to PDF (the content are the graphic images, no OCR processing). Will Kindle Classic be able to view such PDFs? Aren't they too heavy? Acrobat Reader on my old smartphone crashes when trying to open them.

Comment: Assuming Kindle Classic is the non-tablet kind of Kindle then as I remember from when I bought my DX, the  DX can read PDFs (mine can) but the smaller version Kindle could not (that is why I did not by the smaller one).

Comment: I think it's the first-gen that couldn't read PDF. I have a - I believe - second gen, black with keyboard and audio-reading facilities and I can read PDF's on them, though it's hard going and not recommended!